# Namen gleichzeitig als Akkusativ und Dativ benutzen

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

> In meinem Brief habe ich Mike gelobt und gedankt.

Ist dieser Satz grammatikalisch richtig? Kann man den Namen "Mike" gleichzeitig als Akkusativ und Dativ benutzen?

Wenn man den Namen durch ein Pronomen ersetzen will, dann muss man wahrscheinlich so umschreiben:

> In meinem Brief habe ich den Mann gelobt und ihm gedankt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bei einer solchen Konstruktion spricht man von einer *Zusammenziehung*. Auf [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Ordnung/Zusammenziehung.html) gibt es eine schöne Übersicht über die möglichen Konstellationen und auch die zu beachtenden Einschränkungen. Insbesondere heißt es dort:

> Identische Wortformen sollten nicht weggelassen werden, wenn sie nicht im gleichen Fall stehen.

Du solltest also besser schreiben:

> In meinem Brief habe ich Mike gelobt und ihm gedankt.

Answer (score 1):

In Umgangssprache ist die erste Konstruktion auf jeden Fall Gang und Gäbe. Und man hört sicherlich auch Sätze wie:

> In meinem Brief habe ich ihn gelobt und gedankt.

Geschrieben ist die Pronomenvariante, in der man die Fälle unterscheiden kann, nicht mehr möglich; es muss ausgeschrieben werden.

> In meinem Brief habe ich ihm gedankt und ihn gelobt.

Die Namensvariante ist eine Grauzone. Es gibt sicherlich schöneres, aber ich denke, dass man es vielleicht auch überliest. Würde es ein Süddeutsche-Redakteur schreiben, würde er sich ein, zwei Wochen später sicherlich im *Sprachlabor* wiederfinden.