# Verb für mehrere Subjekte: Wann funktioniert diese Ellipse?

Tags: grammar

Ich bin auf folgenden Satz gestoßen, dessen Art ich nie (bewusst) gesehen hatte:

> Mir fiel ein, dass ich ihn später noch einmal bei einem *jour fixe* zu Hause **getroffen**, er mich flehend und kopfschüttelnd **angesehen hatte**.

Es fällt mir auf, dass der verbale Anteil des Nebensatzes (nur hier in Fettschrift) – der sonst für jedes Subjekt sich wiederholt – hier von zweien Subjekten (*ich* und *er*) genutzt wird. Somit scheint *hatte* eine Art Distributivgesetz zu erfüllen.

Ist das üblich? Kann ich weiter das „Gesetz“ anwenden? Etwa in viel trivialerer Sprache:

> 1. Wir konnten uns nicht treffen, weil wir in Deutschland geblieben, sie nach Tschechien gefahren sind.

oder gar:

> 2. Wir konnten uns nicht treffen, weil wir in Deutschland, sie nach Tschechien gefahren sind.

Ich gehe auch davon aus, dass das nicht damit zu tun hat, dass das in Frage kommende Verb in einem Nebensatz ist und dass dies natürlich nur 
möglich ist, weil die konjugierte Form *hatte* für *ich* und *er* die gleiche ist.

Comment: Siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/27427/9091 und http://german.stackexchange.com/a/25581/9091, sowie zum Unterschied zwischen Ellipse und Zusammenziehung: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25590/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-ellipse-und-zusammenziehung

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beispiel 1 funktioniert, Beispiel 2 dagegen nicht. Klar wird dies, wenn man die [Ellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)) ausschreibt:

> 1. Wir konnten uns nicht treffen,
>      weil wir in Deutschland geblieben [**sind**], (und / aber)
>      sie nach Tschechien gefahren [**sind**].

Aber:

> 2. Wir konnten uns nicht treffen,
>      weil wir in Deutschland [**geblieben<sup>1</sup> sind**], (und / aber)
>      sie nach Tschechien gefahren [**sind**].

-> Nur *gleiche* Worte können ausgelassen werden.

Damit geht auch (inhaltlich leicht abgewandelt):

> 3. Wir konnten uns nicht treffen,
>      weil wir in Deutschland [**geblieben sind**], (und / aber)
>      sie in Tschechien [**geblieben sind**].
>      => Wir konnten uns nicht treffen, weil wir in Deutschland, sie in Tschechien geblieben sind.

---

<sup>1</sup> "in Deutschland **gefahren**" wäre nicht idiomatisch.

Comment: @c.p. reines Bauchgefühl als Muttersprachler: 2 geht absolut nicht, wahrscheinlich wegen der Tempora?